# Is it possible to POST Data using localhost woocommerce rest api in flutter

Tags: flutter, localhost, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Is it possible to POST data from flutter app to woocommerce localhost using woocommerce localhost server rest api.

i have GET & POST data with private domain but i want to POST & GET data with localhost woocommerce rest api. i have setup my wordpress and woocommerce on localhost I am trying to make flutter ecommerce app and trying to GET & POST data from woocommerce localhost. but its not working and i dont want to send from private domain rest api, i can get data on postman if i select OAuth 1.0 but if i dont use OAuth 1.0 i cant get data.

Config.dart

```
class Config {
  static String key =
      'ck_00000000000000000000000000';
  static String sceret =
      'cs_00000000000000000000000000';
  static String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/wordpress_new/wp-json/wc/v3/';
  static String customerURL = 'customers';
 }
```

---

customer.dart

```
class CustomerModel {
  String email;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String password;

  CustomerModel({
    this.email,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.password,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};

    map.addAll({
      'email': email,
      'first_name': firstName,
      'last_name': lastName,
      'password': password,
      'username': email,
    });

    return map;
  }
}
```

---

apiservice.dart

```
class APIService {
  Future<bool> createCustomer(CustomerModel model) async {
    var authToken = base64.encode(
      utf8.encode(Config.key + ':' + Config.sceret),
    );

    bool ret = false;
    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(
          Config.url +
              Config.customerURL,
          data: model.toJson(),
          options: new Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $authToken',
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          }));

      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        ret = true;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response.statusCode == 404) {
        print(e.response.statusCode);
        ret = false;
      } else {
        print(e.message);
        print(e.request);
        ret = false;
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }

  Future<LoginResponseModel> loginCustomer(
    String username,
    String password,
  ) async {
    LoginResponseModel model;

    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(Config.tokenURL,
          data: {
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
          },
          options: new Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          }));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        model = LoginResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }

    return model;
  }
}
```

---

signuppage.dart

```
class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  APIService apiService;
  CustomerModel model;
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool hidePassword = true;
  bool isApiCallProcess = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    apiService = new APIService();
    model = new CustomerModel();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Text('Sign Up'),
      ),
      body: ProgressHUD(
          child: Form(
            key: globalKey,
            child: _formUI(),
          ),
          inAsyncCall: isApiCallProcess,
          opacity: 0.3),
    );
  }

  Widget _formUI() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.00),
        child: Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                FormHelper.fieldLabel('First Name'),
                FormHelper.textInput(
                  context,
                  model.firstName,
                  (value) => {
                    this.model.firstName = value,
                  },
                  onValidate: (value) {
                    if (value.toString().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter First Name.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                FormHelper.fieldLabel('Last Name'),
                FormHelper.textInput(
                  context,
                  model.lastName,
                  (value) => {
                    this.model.lastName = value,
                  },
                  onValidate: (value) {
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                FormHelper.fieldLabel('Email Id'),
                FormHelper.textInput(
                  context,
                  model.email,
                  (value) => {
                    this.model.email = value,
                  },
                  onValidate: (value) {
                    if (value.toString().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter Email id.';
                    }
                    if (value.isNotEmpty && !value.toString().isValidEmail()) {
                      return 'Please enter valid email id';
                    }
                  },
                ),
                FormHelper.fieldLabel('Password'),
                FormHelper.textInput(
                  context,
                  model.password,
                  (value) => {
                    this.model.password = value,
                  },
                  onValidate: (value) {
                    if (value.toString().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter Password.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  obscureText: hidePassword,
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                      });
                    },
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                    icon: Icon(
                      hidePassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: FormHelper.saveButton(
                    'Register',
                    () {
                      if (validateAndSave()) {
                        print(model.toJson());
                        setState(() {
                          isApiCallProcess = true;
                        });
                        apiService.createCustomer(model).then(
                          (ret) {
                            setState(() {
                              isApiCallProcess = false;
                            });

                            if (ret) {
                              FormHelper.showMessage(
                                context,
                                'WooCommerce App',
                                'Registration Successfull',
                                'Ok',
                                () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              );
                            } else {
                              FormHelper.showMessage(
                                context,
                                'WooCommerce App',
                                'Email Id already registered.',
                                'Ok',
                                () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

form_helper.dart

```
class FormHelper {
  static Widget textInput(
    BuildContext context,
    Object initialValue,
    Function onChanged, {
    bool isTextArea = false,
    bool isNumberInput = false,
    obscureText: false,
    Function onValidate,
    Widget prefixIcon,
    Widget suffixIcon,
  }) {
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: initialValue != null ? initialValue.toString() : "",
      decoration: fieldDecoration(
        context,
        "",
        "",
        suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
      ),
      obscureText: obscureText,
      maxLines: !isTextArea ? 1 : 3,
      keyboardType: isNumberInput ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.text,
      onChanged: (String value) {
        return onChanged(value);
      },
      validator: (value) {
        return onValidate(value);
      },
    );
  }

  static InputDecoration fieldDecoration(
    BuildContext context,
    String hintText,
    String helperText, {
    Widget prefixIcon,
    Widget suffixIcon,
  }) {
    return InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
      hintText: hintText,
      helperText: helperText,
      prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
      suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          width: 1,
        ),
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          width: 1,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Widget fieldLabel(String labelName) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 10),
      child: Text(
        labelName,
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 15.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Widget saveButton(String buttonText, Function onTap,
      {String color, String textColor, bool fullWidth}) {
    return Container(
      height: 50.0,
      width: 150,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          onTap();
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  buttonText,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static void showMessage(
    BuildContext context,
    String title,
    String message,
    String buttonText,
    Function onPressed,
  ) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(title),
          content: new Text(message),
          actions: [
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                return onPressed();
              },
              child: new Text(buttonText),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

progressHUD.dart

```
class ProgressHUD extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool inAsyncCall;
  final double opacity;
  final Color color;
  final Animation<Color> valueColor;

  ProgressHUD({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.inAsyncCall,
    this.opacity = 0.3,
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.valueColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
    widgetList.add(child);
    if (inAsyncCall) {
      final modal = new Stack(
        children: [
          new Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: color),
          ),
          new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ],
      );
      widgetList.add(modal);
    }
    return Stack(
      children: widgetList,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code related to your post & get requests?

Comment: Thank you for reply, i have update my post with code, and here is local server rest api url that i m trying to access on postman but its not working with localhost link and its only work with private domain.                                    http://localhost/wordpress_new/wp-json/wc/v3/products?cunsumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxxx000000000&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxxxxxx000000000